# Oracle SQL Select Query Getting Max Row As a Fraction of a Rollup Total

Tags: oracle

hoping I might be able to get some advise regarding Oracle SQL…

I have a table roughly as follows (there are more columns, but not necessary for this example)…

```
LOCATION        USER        VALUE
1               1           10
1               2           20
1               3           30
2               4           10
2               5           10
2               6           20
1                           60
2                           40
                            100
```

I’ve used rollup to get subtotals.

What I need to do is get the max(value) row for each location and express the max(value) as a percentage or fraction of the subtotal for each location

ie:

```
LOCATION        USER        FRAC
1               3           0.5
2               6           0.5
```

I could probably solve this using my limited knowledge of select queries, but am guessing there must be a fairly quick and slick method..

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you show what you tried so far ? I guess, it's better than nothing !

Comment: what version of Oracle are you in?  (FYI: "USER" is a reserved word, use a different column name ... "CUSER" ?? maybe ?)   Hint:  Look into "ratio_to_report" analytic function if your version supports it:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions142.htm#SQLRF00691

Comment: I've written something completely different, before I discovered 'rollup'. So I had the total for each location in a separate column. The problem is my query is a bit long winded and slow which is why I was hoping there might be some simple method for you experts.

Comment: Thanks 'Ditto'... I just used the term 'user' for my example above. I'm off to research ratio_to_report now. Not sure what version we are using - I only use Toad to run queries and change some basic data.

Comment: `select version from v$instance;` will show you the version

Comment: Aha... version 12.1.0.1.0

Comment: I've managed to solve it using grouping sets and ratio_to_report - Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution using **analytic functions**

(Please note the WITH MY_TABLE AS serving only as dummy datasource)

```
WITH MY_TABLE AS
  ( SELECT 1 AS LOC_ID,1 AS USER_ID, 10 AS VAL FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 1,2,20 FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 1,3,30 FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 2,4,10 FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 2,5,10 FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 2,6,20 FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT LOC_ID,
  USER_ID,
  RATIO_IN_LOC
FROM
  (SELECT LOC_ID,
    USER_ID,
    RATIO_IN_LOC,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY LOC_ID ORDER BY RATIO_IN_LOC DESC) AS ORDER_IN_LOC
  FROM
    (SELECT LOC_ID,
      USER_ID,
      VAL,
      VAL/SUM(VAL) OVER (PARTITION BY LOC_ID) AS RATIO_IN_LOC
    FROM MY_TABLE
    )
  )
WHERE ORDER_IN_LOC = 1
ORDER BY LOC_ID,
  USER_ID;
```

**Result**

```
LOC_ID  USER_ID RATIO_IN_LOC
1       3       0,5
2       6       0,5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with inputs ( location, person, value ) as (
       select 1, 1, 10 from dual union all
       select 1, 2, 20 from dual union all
       select 1, 3, 30 from dual union all
       select 2, 4, 10 from dual union all
       select 2, 5, 10 from dual union all
       select 2, 6, 20 from dual
     ),
     prep ( location, person, value, m_value, total ) as (
       select location, person, value,
              max(value) over (partition by location),
              sum(value) over (partition by location)
       from   inputs
     )
select location, person, round(value/total, 2) as frac
from   prep
where  value = m_value;
```

Notes:  Your table exists already? Then skip everything from "inputs" to the comma; your query should begin with `with prep (...) as ( ...`

I changed `user` to `person` since `user` is a keyword in Oracle, you shouldn't use it for table or column names (actually you can't unless you use double quotes, which is a very poor practice).

The query will output two or three or more rows per location if there are ties at the top. Presumably this is what you desire.

Output:

```
  LOCATION     PERSON       FRAC
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          3         .5
         2          6         .5
```